# MySQL Self referencing table, display hierarchy in one row with combined fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following self-referencing table. Note: this table has been greatly simplified for this question, there are thousands of rows in this table.

```
TABLE_A
--------------------------------
  ID     TABLE_A_ID     TITLE
--------------------------------
  1         null        base_1
  2           1         title_2
  3           2         title_3
  4         null        base_4
  5           4         title_5
  6           5         title_6
  7           6         title_7      
  8         null        base_8
  9           8         title_9
```

The scenario I have is that I need to retrieve a row BUT the title must contain the details of all parent rows, so if i was trying to return row with ID 3, 7 and 9 I need the following

```
-----------------------------------
  ID       TITLE
-----------------------------------
  3        base_1, title_2, title_3
  7        base_4, title_5, title_6, title_7
  9        base_8, title_9
```

Ive looked at using GROUP_CONCAT but that doesn't seem to be the right approach. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to write a stored procedure. MySQL still doesn't support recursive queries

Comment: Great, really helpful. So what you are saying is I need to write some code to solve this. Genius

Comment: Yes (or upgrade to a DBMS where this could be done with a single statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by writing a custom function which retrieves/loops through the ID provided until it reaches the base and returns the concatenated string.

```
Name:    GetAllTitles
Input:   InputID

Steps:   `While ID <> null
{
    select TABLE_A_ID,title from table where ID='InputID';
    If TABLE_A_ID is not null then,
    {
        // Save title to temp
        // Save TABLE_A_ID to InputID
        return CONCAT(temp,GetAllTitles(InputID));
    }
    else {  return emptystring;
    }
}`
```

Final SQL Query would be:
select ID,GetAllTitles(ID) from TABLE A